# Display message after image uploaded

Tags: javascript

We are trying to upload an image from [This site](http://stylebaby.com/custom-apple-iphone-4.html).

1. we click on "**Upload Image**" button.

[image]

2. then it will display **pop up** box.

[image]

3. Then we click on **Upload New image** button
4. After that, we will select image from computer
5. Then again we click on "**Add image**" button to display image on site.

Here after 4th step is done, we want to display message **Image uploaded** below "Upload New image" text.

What am I missing in this code?

```js
initialize: function($super, params) {

    $super(params);
    this.template =
      '<div id="customproductrelay" class="customproductrelay" style="display: none;">
                <div id="fancyusercustimg" class="modal-dialog" style="display:none;">
                <a class="closecustom" onclick="closePopup()" href="#"></a>
                <div class="modal-content"><div id="aitcg-tool-' + this.toolKey + '" class="tool-body">' +
      '<div class="uploadimg" id="uploadimg"><div class="fileinput-button padded text-center" >
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i><span >Upload New Image</span>
                    <input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" class="newcustomimage" name="new_image" /></div></div>' +
      '<br />' +
      '<div style="display:none;"  id="add_image_{{rand}}_error" class="validation-advice">{{required_text}}</div>' +
      this._getUnderTemplateSelectHtml() +
      '<div class="buttons">' +
      '<button class="aitcg-button apply" type="button" id="submit-user-image-{{rand}}">{{addimage_text}}</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div></div></div></div>';
  },

  // Submit image to the server

  submit: function() {
    var id = 'add_image_' + this.tools.config.rand;

    if (!$(id).value) {
      $(id + '_error').show();
      return;
    }
    $(id + '_error').hide();

    Aitcg.showLoader();
    AIM.upload(this.config.requestUrl, id, {
      onComplete: this.loadUploadedImage.bind(this)
    });
  },

  //For Displaying message

  success: function($super, params) {

    return params.previewElement.classList.add("Image uploaded");
  }
```

Comment: `return params.previewElement.classList.add("Image uploaded");`. You are not displaying any text. You are just adding class to the previewElement.

Comment: @makshh sorry for that , i am new to JS & Thanks for pointing that , let me try to display message `image uploaded`

Comment: use `innerHTML` for that. And I don't know what is `previewElement`, you didn't show your whole code.

Comment: @makshh i just used `previewElement` to display message, i thought `previewElement` will work, as you said , i will try with `innerHtml`....

Comment: @makshh i am trying this : `function display1() {

     document.getElementById(add_image_{{rand}}).innerHTML="message";

    }` but its hiding "Add image" button, what wrong i am doing ?

Comment: `innerHTML+="messa‌​ge"`, add `+` sign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134755/discussion-between-user5348fh8y5-and-makshh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.template = 
        '<div id="aitcg-tool-' + this.toolKey + '" class="tool-body">' +
            '<input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" name="new_image" />' +
            '<br />' +
            '<div style="display:none;" id="add_image_{{rand}}_error" class="validation-advice">{{required_text}}</div>' +
            this._getUnderTemplateSelectHtml() +
            '<div class="buttons">' +
                '<button class="aitcg-button" type="button" id="submit-user-image-{{rand}}">{{addimage_text}}</button>'+
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';
```

replace this.template with

```
    this.template = 
    '<div id="aitcg-tool-' + this.toolKey + '" class="tool-body">' +
        '<input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" name="new_image"/><br/>'                +           '<div style="display:none;" id="add_image_{{rand}}_error"
         class="validation-advice">{{required_text}}</div><div style="display:none;" id="add_image_{{rand}}_success" class="validation-advice">File Uploded</div>' + this._getUnderTemplateSelectHtml() +
         '<div class="buttons">' +
               '<button class="aitcg-button" type="button" id="submit-user-image-{{rand}}">{{addimage_text}}</button>'+
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';
```

after this change loadUploadedImage function

```
loadUploadedImage: function( url )
{
    if (!url.error) {
        var img = $$('.techimg')[0];
        $$('.techimg').each(function(elem) {
            if(elem.parentNode.visible()){img = elem;}
        });
        img.onload = function(e){
            this.addImage(Aitcg.getEventTarget(e));
            Aitcg.hideLoader();
        }.bind(this);
        img.src = url.src;
    } else {
        Aitcg.hideLoader();
        alert(url.error);
    }
},
```

replace it with

```
 loadUploadedImage: function( url )
 {            
    if (!url.error) {
    $('add_image_' + this.tools.config.rand+'_success').show();
        var img = $$('.techimg')[0];
        $$('.techimg').each(function(elem) {
            if(elem.parentNode.visible()){img = elem;}
        });
        img.onload = function(e){
            this.addImage(Aitcg.getEventTarget(e));
            Aitcg.hideLoader();
        }.bind(this);
        img.src = url.src;           
    } else {
        Aitcg.hideLoader();
        alert(url.error);
    }
},
```

Comment: sorry for delay, Thanks for answer, updated your code, but still same result, i am not seeing any message in pop up..... , please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be by adding a blank span tag under `<span >Upload New Image</span>`

**HTML MARKUP:**

```
<span>Upload New Image</span></br>
<span id="spnMessage"></span>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
//For Displaying message

  success: function($super, params) {

    $("#spnMessage").html("Image Uploaded");
    return params.previewElement.classList.add("Image uploaded");
  }
```

---

You need to update your template, you code look like this

```
this.template =
      '<div id="customproductrelay" class="customproductrelay" style="display: none;">
                <div id="fancyusercustimg" class="modal-dialog" style="display:none;">
                <a class="closecustom" onclick="closePopup()" href="#"></a>
                <div class="modal-content"><div id="aitcg-tool-' + this.toolKey + '" class="tool-body">' +
      '<div class="uploadimg" id="uploadimg"><div class="fileinput-button padded text-center" >
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i><span >Upload New Image</span></br>
<span id="spnMessage"></span>
                    <input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" class="newcustomimage" name="new_image" /></div></div>' +
      '<br />' +
      '<div style="display:none;"  id="add_image_{{rand}}_error" class="validation-advice">{{required_text}}</div>' +
      this._getUnderTemplateSelectHtml() +
      '<div class="buttons">' +
      '<button class="aitcg-button apply" type="button" id="submit-user-image-{{rand}}">{{addimage_text}}</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div></div></div></div>';
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually we wrote all these buttons code in `.Js file` , so is html code work in .js file  ? or is there any chance can you please give me code to solve the issue with js code only.....

Comment: i updated code, but now `Add image`button is not displaying , please check [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake , after placing your code, still `add image button` were displayin, but once i upload image from local computer, its not displaying any message in pop up....